# Compare arrays golang

Tags: arrays, go, compare

I have defined my own type in Go:

```
type Sha1Hash [20]byte
```

I would like to sort two of these hashes, h1 and h2:

```
func Compare(h1, h2 Sha1Hash) int {

    h1 >= h2 // doens't work, arrays only have == and !=
    bytes.Compare(h1,h2) //doesn't work, Compare only works on slices

}
```

How can I  compare my arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can form a slice from an array:

```
func Compare(h1, h2 Sha1Hash) int {
    return bytes.Compare(h1[0:20], h2[0:20]) 
}
```

Comment: Or just `h1[:], h2[:]`.